# SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I want the user to insert date in the form. Can you please tell me how can I insert the date in my view. Whenever I enter the value in the form it gives this error.

My PlaneSchedule Model as follows.

```
  public class Plane_Schedule
        {
            [Key]
            public int Plane_id { get; set; }
            public int PlaneSch_id { get; set; }
            public string  Plane_LocTo { get; set; }
            public string  Plane_LocFrom { get; set; }
            public DateTime Time_Dep { get; set; }
            public DateTime Time_Arrive { get; set; }
            public virtual List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        }
```

The action in Controller as follows

```
[HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult SaveSchedule(AirlineWebApplication.Models.Plane_Schedule Plane_Schedule, HttpPostedFileBase file)
            {

                db.Plane_Schedule.Add(Plane_Schedule);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

The PlaneSchedule view as follows

```
<section class="registersection">
     <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="signupForm">
                 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                 <form action="~/Plane_Schedule/SaveSchedule" method="post">
                       @using (Html.BeginForm())
                         {
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                                    <div class="Form1">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                                <div class="editor-field">
                                                    <label>
                                                        FROM
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Plane_LocFrom)
                                                    </label>
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Plane_LocFrom)
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                                <div class="editor-field">
                                                    <label>
                                                        TO
                                 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Plane_LocTo)
                                                    </label>
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Plane_LocTo)
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
                                                </p>

                                }
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Please tell me how can I insert the date from a user in the View Model and save it in the database?

Comment: You do not have any inputs for `Time_Dep` and `Time_Arrive` (so they are the default `1/1/0001`). You also have nested forms which is invalid html

Comment: Can you please tell me how to input datetime in the form?? I have tried its giving the same error.

Comment: What did you try? (its just `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Time_Dep)`)

Comment: Yes. I tried this.

Comment: (1) - That is not in your question! (2) If you have entered a valid date, it will not give an error (and you always check if `ModelState` is valid before saving anything)

Comment: I have used this but error is still there <div class="editor-field">
                                                <label>
                                                    TO
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time_Dep)
                                                </label>
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Time_Dep)
                                            </div>

Comment: Then you have not entered a valid date!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Stephen!